# running Matlab on background BASH #2

Tags: bash, matlab, background

I'm running the following loop that's supposed to run several proccesses simutanuesly on a server in the background:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= n; i++)); do

matlab -nojvm -r "pth=path(/myfold);addpath(pth);script1;pause(1);func1(i,n);clear;exit" </dev/null &

done
```

the background command is not suspended (tnx Dennis Williamson) but the results I get are:

1.
the annotation:

```
 [1] 1000
 [2] 2000
 [3] 3000
 [4] 4000
 [5] 5000
```

2.
the matlab nojvm txt

```
 [1]   Done       'name of the above command'
 [2]   Done       'name of the above command'
 [3]   Done       'name of the above command'
 [4]-  Done       'name of the above command'
 [5]+  Done       'name of the above command'
```

when I use `ps` or `top` to see the processes there are none.

This script needs to run at least an hour and I don't get the results that it needs to produce.
Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Comment: The semicolon after the ampersand will produce an error. Ampersands perform the role of semicolons as command delimiters.

Comment: it was a mistake while writing the question, I run the code without it (corrected at the Question)

Comment: instead of running `matlab`, can you add an `echo` before it, remove the `&` and then run your command. That will give you whether the parameters are peing passed correctly or not. From the code, I feel that the value of `i` and `n` is not being passed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use *$i* and *$n* in the command instead of *i* and *n*, as in:

```
matlab -nojvm -r "pth=path(/myfold);addpath(pth);script1;pause(1);func1($i,$n);clear;exit" </dev/null &
```